# HTML in Spark TextArea

Tags: actionscript, mobile, flex4

Trying to add some html to a TextArea in Mobile Flex 4.5 but keep getting the error:

> "1180: Call to a possibly undefined
>   method StyleableTextField."

For the following line:

```
StyleableTextField(txtMyText.textDisplay).htmlText = "sample <b>text</b>";
```

Comment: Keep in mind that because this is a mobile app textFlow property doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like:

```
MobileTextField(txtMyText.textDisplay).htmlText = "sample <b>text</b>";
```

works. Just needed to import:

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.MobileTextField;
```

to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the htmlText property of the TextArea instance directly?

Something like this:

```
myTextArea.htmlText = "sample <b>text</b>";
```

Rob

Comment: That triggers:

Access of possibly undefined property htmlText through a reference with static type spark.components:TextArea